# How to Printing Network Path document client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I have documents stored in NAS network. Now I want to print those documents using javasrcipt in Internet Explorer Edge. Below is the code which I am trying to execute but its not able to print

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebPrintTest.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script>

    printPdf = function (url) {
        var iframe = this._printIframe;
        if (!this._printIframe) {
            iframe = this._printIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);

            iframe.style.display = 'none';
            iframe.onload = function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    iframe.focus();
                    iframe.contentWindow.print();
                }, 1);
            };
        }

        iframe.src = url;
    }

    printPdf("\\ad\NAS\PrintDoc\Sample.docx");

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

What's wrong in my code or approach?

I am getting error as

```
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference
```

at

```
 document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: You doubled the first backslash in the path but not the others ...

Comment: @Pointy I doubled remaining too but still its giving same eror

Comment: What error is that? Don't you think that would be helpful to people trying to diagnose your problem?

Comment: in JS strings backslash *escapes* the next character. If you want *one* backslash, you need to put two in the string. So if you need two in the beginning, you need four in the string.

Comment: @Pointy Its giving error as `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference` at `document.body.appendChild(iframe);`

Comment: Move your `<script>` block to the very end of the `<body>`. That error happens because when the script runs the body has not yet been added to the DOM.

Comment: @Pointy WOW..That error is gone but I am getting new error as `0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.`  at ` iframe.contentWindow.print();`. I do have access of the path..As per comment from @vlaz I added one backslash extra in my path

Comment: OK, well now your problem is that the browser doesn't like the idea of accessing local files on the client machine. It's basic security. I wasn't sure if you had some weird Microsoft setup that would allow Edge to access the file, but apparently not.

Comment: @Pointy..Ok Got it..So, Can I access my System's C drive file? Will it be allowed?

Comment: It goes against security policy to be able to access the local file system with Javascript. There are some browser-specific ways I think but they're very prone to bugs and not cross-browser compatible at all like WebkitGetAsEntry